# Font size as rem not working on mac

Tags: html, css, asp.net, macos

I have following inline style on asp label ,

```
style="font-size:.75rem;line-height:1.8rem;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;"
```

When I am making any changes to font size,

```
   style="font-size:.55rem;line-height:1.8rem;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;"
```

I could see the changes on windows and chrome with Incognito mode , however if I switch to mac and then use chrome (incognito) then could not see these changes.

Am I missing out anything here?

Comment: What's showing up in your developer tools?

Comment: Check the user preferences on your browsers. If you have a minimum font size set, the browser won't use smaller font sizes than that. For instance if your default font size is 12px and the minimum font size is 9px, then the browser won't display anything at smaller than .75rem.